# getting empty response from RETS server using PHrets

Tags: rets, phrets

I got connected to RETS Server and i am able to get all metadata using functions in PHrets library like GetMetadataResources,GetMetadataClasses,and all feilds in each class,but i am unable to get data from that server using SearchQuery,I tried in all ways but no luck.

```
<pre>
    /* Initialize Object */
 require("PHRets_CREA.php");
require("credentials.php");
$rets = new PHRets();
$connect=$rets->Connect($RETSURL, $RETSUsername, $RETSPassword);
    /* Connect */
    /* Query Server */
    if ($connect) {
        echo "Connected";
$resources = $rets->GetMetadataResources();
foreach ($resources as $resource) {
        echo "+ Resource {$resource['ResourceID']}\n";
        $classes = $rets->GetMetadataClasses($resource['ResourceID']);
        foreach ($classes as $class) {
                echo "   + Class {$class['ClassName']} described as " . $class['Description'] . "\n";
        $rets_metadata = $rets->GetMetadata($resource['ResourceID'],$class['ClassName']);
        foreach ($rets_metadata as $field) {
            echo "    + Field: {$field['SystemName']} ({$field['DataType']})\n";
        }
        }
}
/*
$search = $rets->SearchQuery("Property","RE_1","(L_ListingDate=2010-03-02-2010-03-03)");
while ($listing = $rets->FetchRow($search)) {
  echo $listing['L_ListingID'];
        }*/
$search = $rets->SearchQuery("Property","ResidentialProperty","(ListDate=1990-01-01+)",
array( "Count" => 1, "Format" => "COMPACT", "Limit" => "2", "Offset" => "2",
"RestrictedIndicator" => "****", "StandardNames" => 1 )
);
echo "data";
print_r($search);
while ($listing = $rets->FetchRow($search)) 
 echo "{$listing['L_City']}";exit; 
}
$rets->FreeResult($search);
}</pre>

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your Resource and Class name are correct. Use http://retsmd.com to verify. Resource is usually "Property" but check your Class name which you currently have to "ResidentialProperty". It may be "RE_1" which you had in your above code.

Next, modify your SearchQuery. Maybe use less parameters in the options array and try removing StandardNames and use the default System Names.

Something like this:

```
$search = $rets->SearchQuery("Property","RE_1","(L_ListingDate=1990-01-01+)", array("Limit" => "10"));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.I already verified in  http://retsmd.com/ ,both resources and class names are correct ,eventhough i used above search query i am getting empty array for print_r($search),but data is there in RETS server

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one, we get all active properties for this.

$search = $rets->SearchQuery("Property","1","(135=1990-01-01+),(246=A)");